# up route add for interface that already has gateway defined

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, linux-networking

My current `/etc/network/interfaces` in Ubuntu 17.04 has a `up route add -net 173.xxx.xxx.0/24 gw 173.xxx.xxx.1 dev eth0` line even though the interface already defines that gateway:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 173.xxx.xxx.108
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 173.xxx.xxx.1
    dns-nameservers xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
    dns-search xxxxx.net

up route add -net 173.xxxx.xxxx.0/24 gw 173.xxxx.xxxx.1 dev eth0
```

Is that last line even needed?

Comment: If  `173.xxx.xxx`. has the same value everywhere the `up route` statement is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Is the `gateway 173.xxx.xxx.1` the exact same address as the `...gw 173.xxxx.xxxx.1 ...`?  If identical it probably isn't needed.  If different then it may be needed.  Since you have censored everything it is hard to tell.

It is also possible something like a VPN, or or other service at a later point gets started that changes the default gateway.  That route is could be added specifically to make sure you can reach a local networks if something changes the default route.  So if you are running some kind of VPN on this box you may still need that route even if the gateway is the same.

Comment: The gateway is identical, yes. There is no VPN set-up on the machine.